# Cannot load certain images with Fireabse storage UI (SD web image)

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-storage, sdwebimage

I'm struggling to figure out why only **certain** images load from Firebase Storage using SD Web Image (via FirebaseStorageUI). I even have two copies of the same image under different names, and only one of the two loads and appears when assigned to my button. All images are .jpg and are under 100kb and are stored in the same /images folder.

Here's the code where I get the image from Firebase storage, and assign it to a button (in an array of buttons):

```
    let imagename = "gs://xxxxxx.appspot.com/images/bruce.jpg"
    let reference = FIRStorage.storage().reference(forURL: imagename)

    if iDs != nil {
        for i in 0..<iDs!.count {

            let storageImage = UIImageView()

            let placeholderImage = UIImage(named: "fong")

            // Load the image using SDWebImage and assign to button
            storageImage.sd_setImage(with: reference, placeholderImage: placeholderImage)

            self.arbtrButtons[i].setImage(storageImage.image, for: .normal)
```

Comment: Are you getting an error or anything else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to have been caused by a duplicate variable name outside the scope of the function, which was causing my array of firebase references to be nil at the time of assignment from Firebase. The only images that loaded were ones that had already been cashed before I created the duplicate variable name. By some fluke of network speed, the user data had once or twice managed to load before the variable was assigned a nil array, and thus I had two images in cash, while all other images would not load.